# How to translate "Filter by" in magento 2

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate

I want to translate Filter by text:

[image]

I have translated it in app/i18n/es_ES.csv and in app/design/frontend/.../Theme/i18n/es_ES.csv but this doesn´t work. I have tried all the possibilities:

[image]

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. There's no chance to translate "Filter by" with the csv file.
I resolved the problem editing config.xml in this location html/app/code/Theme/Ajaxlayernavigation/etc

[image]

If you founded another method let me know, but this way works for me

Comment: Ou yeaaaah! Thaaanks

Answer (score 0):

By default in Magento 2, "**Filter by**" text is not available,
So make sure that the text printed in the file from the theme or module has used the standard Magento 2 coding standard like.

```
<?php echo __('Filter by'); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, the text printed is correct, but the translation doesn´t work. :(

Comment: Have you added the module name in csv with the word you want to translate, like Magento_Catalog ?